# ng-model on select in AngularJS + JQM works partly

Tags: jquery-mobile, angularjs

For app based on AngularJS, JQuery Mobile and JQuery Mobile Angular Adapter.

When i set ng-controller on tag with data-role="page", ng-model on select tag works perfectly:

```
<body ng-app>
    <div data-role="page" id="product" ng-controller="Controller">
        <div data-role="content">
            <select ng-model="color" ng-options="c for c in colors"></select>
            <button ng-click="Print()">print</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ilya7u/Ddt7G/

When ng-controller present in body tag, variable associated with select tag through ng-model remains unchanged:

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
    <div data-role="page" id="product">
        <div data-role="content">
            <select ng-model="color" ng-options="c for c in colors"></select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ilya7u/qgbj2/

Why and how i can fix it? I want to use one controller in app with many pages!

Comment: This seems to be working fine in Chrome. How are you testing?

Comment: Testing under Chrome, Safari! Open http://jsfiddle.net/ilya7u/qgbj2/, change color from red to white or black, than check $scope.color. $scope.color will be 'red'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like there are really two scopes here. The page has its own scope, but the Print is in the parent scope. I've updated the fiddle to show that the color does indeed change, but the $scope.color in Print does not: http://jsfiddle.net/qgbj2/6/

To remedy this particular situation, I would pass in the color to Print from the DOM:

```
    <body ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
        <div data-role="page" id="product">
            <div data-role="content">
                <select ng-model="color" ng-options="c for c in colors"></select>
                <button ng-click="Print(color)">print</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

A general solution for this multiple scope situation does not occur to me at the moment.

Comment: You are right, thanks! I found the documentation about this. My mistake - use before read docs. Ex: "Every page of jquery mobile gets a separate scope." and solution: "For communicating between the pages use the ngm-shared-controller directive"

Answer (score 2):

including the ng-app in the html of your page will solve the problem

try

```
<html ng-app="myModule">
<body ng-controller="Controller">
    <div id="product" >
        <div data-role="content">
            <select ng-model="color" ng-options="c for c in colors"></select>
            <button ng-click="Print()">print</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and change the controller to

```
var myApp = angular.module('myModule',[]);
myApp.controller('Controller', function($scope) {
   $scope.colors = ['red', 'black', 'white'];
    $scope.color = $scope.colors[0];

    $scope.Print = function () {
        alert($scope.color);
    };
});
```

updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/qgbj2/2/

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing has changed

Comment: yes, it works! but when i set JQM attr data-role="page" in <div id="product"> ng-model stay unchanged!